# Facebook Opengraph tags are not working in joomla 3.3 while Gzip page Compression is enabled

Tags: joomla, metadata, gzip, facebook-opengraph

I have a joomla 3.2 site - http://test.guru99.com. To display content in facebook link share on wall post every page must contain Opengraph meta tags present in the page head. i had used a plugin, All og meta tags were present in the page source when i checked it so plugin was working fine and there was no issue with it.

So I did few searching on web and found that if i `disable Gzip Page Compression from Admin -> Global Configuration ->Server.` Then Everything works fine. I again enabled the Gzip Page compression and checked now it's not displaying.

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="og:title" content="Home" />
  <meta name="og:type" content="article" />
  <meta name="og:image" content="http://test.guru99.com/images/app_google_play(1).png" />
  <meta name="og:url" content="http://test.guru99.com/" />
  <meta name="og:site_name" content="Guru99" />
  <meta name="og:description" content="This is where your Meta description goes" />
```

So, I searched the web, many people had the same issue but no one has the proper solution.

My Question is Why facebook's opengraph and Gzip page compression is not working together.
As Gzip is also recommended by google and required. i must need Gzip enabled on my site

Any solution or settings that i can tweak ?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook scraps ALWAYS the first 40k of data of a given page. That means if your page is more than that (the compressed one) then it will be partially downloaded, and because is compressed it will be broken. Needs some logic so that when the request is from Facebook, page will not be compressed

Here's a solution for this [Joomla Facebookfix Plugin](https://github.com/dgt41/facebookfix)

Answer (score 1):

Gzip compression and facebook scrapping is a well know issue on Joomla, please read the article bellow and you'll find the link to a plugin on JED that disables gzip for facebook and linkedin user agents.

https://www.bennetonable.com/blog/joomla/comment-resoudre-le-probleme-de-partage-sur-facebook-lorsque-gzip-est-actif

The original is in French but here's a google translation:

> Enabling gzip compression on Joomla causes problems when you want to share its content on Facebook. This widespread problem is easy to get around thanks to a very clever plugin.
>
> If you want to solve this problem simply install a small plugin called gzip very friendly Control: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/site-performance/27725
>
> This plugin disables by default Gzip your html code for bots Facebook and Linkedin that scan your site every time a user shares one of your pages.
>
> It also allows you to specify the names of other bots that would be likely to cause problems with compressed html content.
>
> If you have JCH Optimize module installed on your site you will need to disable gzip compression offered by the module. All other options can remain activated without any problems, including a native Joomla gzip compression.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This fix made my 3.1.1 site complete white on the front-end.

Comment: Link is dead :)